# Is the logarithm of a PSD quadratic form concave?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Is $\mathrm{log}(\mathbf{x}^{H}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x})$ concave in $\mathbf{x}$ for $\mathbf{A}$ positive semidefinite (i.e., $\mathbf{A}\succeq\boldsymbol{\mathbf{0}}$)? I know that this is true for the special case that both $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{A}$ are real scalars; consider the following:

$$\mathrm{log}(xax)=log(x^{2}a)=2log(x)+log(a)$$

Clearly, the logarithm of $ax^2$ is concave even though the original quadratic function is convex. My question is whether or not this extends to the more general case described at the start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. For dimension $\ge 2$, this is generally neither convex nor concave, as the following examples show.

Consider dimension 2, and let the matrix $A$ be the identity matrix.  Pick two points, x1 and x2. Let $x3 = .5*(x1+x2)$

```
>> x1=[2;2];x2=[2;3];x3=.5*(x1+x2);log(x3'*x3)-.5*(log(x1'*x1)+log(x2'*x2))
ans =
   0.005082256013731
>> x1=[2;3];x2=[4;2];x3=.5*(x1+x2);log(x3'*x3)-.5*(log(x1'*x1)+log(x2'*x2))
ans =
  -0.055761312454343
```

Comment: Thanks for showing this @Mark L. Stone!